# javascript regex for matching all strings that isn't a specified string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that looks like the following:

`var myRegex = /%([a-z_]*)%/i`

This matches any substring such as `%foo%` where a string is between two quotes.

What's the best way to modify this regex so that it only matches when the regex matches when `%` surrounds anything BUT the string `foo`? So it won't match `%foo%` but it would match `%bar_%` `%anythingelse%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a negative lookahead here:

```
var myRegex = /%(?!foo%)([a-z_]*)%/i;
```

`(?!foo%)` is negative lookahead that will assert failure when we have `foo%` is ahead of `%` thus failing `%foo%`.

Comment: Wouldn't this incorrectly not match `%foolkajsdksad%`?

Comment: @Jay No, because `foo%` is a string literal. There are no wildcards between `foo` and `%`

Comment: @Jay Nope, because the negative lookahead looks for `foo%` instead of `foo`

Comment: what about `%alskjdfoo%`?

Comment: So I tested it out, but I'm not really sure why it should match that string haha